# Decoding h264 stream using direct3d11 in gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer, h.264, direct3d11

I am trying to use GStreamer command lines to capture a video that I stream over my network. In order to improve performance, I need to make use of hardware acceleration. I decided to use Direct3D11, because I'm limited to a PC with Windows OS and an Intel graphic card (Intel(R) UHD Graphics 620).

This is the command line I'm using:
`gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc uri=udp://224.10.10.10:11000 ! h264parse ! d3d11h264dec ! d3d11convert ! d3d11videosink sync=false`.
The problem is that the decoding seems to produce [faulty frames](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGZYN.png).
For instance it generated this [faulty frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGZYN.png). These frames change slightly every second
and change significantly every 5 to 10 seconds.
This is the [stream codec](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4oCY.png) according to VLC.

Am I missing properties or pads? Should I use other plugins?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the problem was caused as a result of picking the wrong plugin for parsing the stream.
I ended up using the generic parser "parsebin" instead of "h264parse" which worked perfectly for my stream.